# Python gevent pool.spawn() handling exception

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, gevent

I have a function like this

```
     for url in allurl:
            try:
                    pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
                    pool.spawn(crawler, url)
                    pool.join()
            except:
                    allurl.append(url)
```

I want the exception can handling the errors, so I can crawl all the urls, but it seems doesn't work.

Can someone tell me whats wrong? Is there any other solution or suggestion?

Comment: What is your traceback, that allow know more information, update post with it please.

Comment: When it run finish, i find there some url didn't crawl, it didn't append the allurl.